# Java OOP Data Access

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, dns

I am usually programming in Java and I am using common patterns (DAO,Factorys, ..).
In most cases, it is needed to hold global accessible data (for example game entities in a game could be requested by several windows). Where to save the global data? Is there a solution which is scalable?

Comment: Create a `GameContext` class. Have it hold any game objects. Pass an instance of this class around, ie. let everyone have access to it. Don't make it static.

Comment: Thanks, I read a bit about dependency injection. Would you prefeer passing the objects by using setters or constructors, or is it just personal preference? I wonder if there is a real reason for not making the class static?

Comment: It doesn't really matter how you pass them. You don't necessarily need a reference to the object in your instance. Just pass it in the methods and use it there. There are arguments against using `static` data structures for storing data. You can read up on those and make your own decision.

Answer (score 0):

the static data structures will occupy your too much memory.So you shouldn't use static data structures unless you have to use it